Trace Inspector failed to start because of failing to check version
エラーが解消できません。
環境はdockerはWindows環境で構築して
AppはWindows環境でVSCodeでWSL(ubuntu)ターミナルで、
修正・実行しいます。
'gem debug' をGemfileに記載しています
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem 'takarabako'
  gem 'gimei'
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
  gem 'debase'
  gem 'debug', '>= 1.8.0'
end

その際に、 'rm -rf Gemfile.lock' 'bundle install' 'docker compose down' 'docker compose up -d --build'　を実行しています。
Web App はChromeで立ち上がり操作できています、
docker container の'app' と 'db　は正常に立ち上がっています。
しかし、debuを実行すると'Trace Inspector failed to start because of failing to check version' のメッセージが添付画像のように出力されます。
Trace Inspector の’Enable Trace’ボタンを押下すると、「Trace Inspector failed to start because of the version of debug.gem was less than 1.8.0. Please update the version.　　VSC rdbg Ruby Debbuger」とエラーメッセージが表示されます。
gem debugをVSCodeがうまく認識できてないのでしょうか。
どうすればよいでしょうか。

【launch.json】
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "rdbg",
      "name": "Debug current file with rdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "script": "${file}",
      "args": [],
      "askParameters": true,
      "useTerminal": true
    }
  ]
}

【setting.json】
{
  "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PATH": "/home/username/.rbenv/shims:/home/username/.rbenv/bin:${env:PATH}"
  },
  "ruby.rdbgPath": "/home/username/.rbenv/shims/rdbg"
}

